# How can I take ownership of a collection using range-v3?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I want to return a range from a function that represents a view on a STL collection, something like this:

```
auto createRange() {
    std::unordered_set<int> is = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    return is | view::transform([](auto&& i) {
        return i;
    });
}
```

However, `view::transform` does not take ownership of `is`, so when I run this, there is undefined behavior, because `is` is freed when `createRange` exits.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto rng = createRange();
    ranges::for_each(rng, [](auto&& i) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
    });
}
```

If I try `std::move(is)` as the input, I get a static assert indicating that I can't use rvalue references as inputs to a `view`. Is there any way to ensure that the view takes ownership of the collection?

### Edit: Some Additional Info

I want to add some clarifying info. I have a stream of data, `data` that I have a view on that transforms the data into a struct, `Foo`, that looks something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string name;
    std::unordered_set<int> values;
}

// Take the input stream and turn it into a range of Foos
auto foos = data | asFoo();
```

What I want to do is create a range of `std::pair<std::string, int>` by distributing the name throughout the values. My naive attempt looks something like this:

```
auto result = data | asFoo() | view::transform([](auto&& foo) {
    const auto& name = foo.name;
    const auto& values = foo.values;
    return values | view::transform([name](auto&& value) {
        return std::make_pair(name, value);
    }
}) | view::join;
```

However, this results in the undefined behavior because `values` is freed. The only way that I have been able to get around this is to make `values` a `std::shared_ptr` and to capture it in the lambda passed to `view::transform` to preserve it's lifetime. That seems like an inelegant solution.

I think what I am looking for is a view that will take ownership of the source collection, but it does not look like range-v3 has that.

Alternatively, I could just create the distributed version using a good old fashioned for-loop, but that does not appear to work with `view::join`:

```
auto result = data | asFoo() | view::transform([](auto&& foo) {
    const auto& name = foo.name;
    const auto& values = foo.values;

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> distributedValues;
    for (const auto& value : values) {
        distributedValues.emplace_back(name, value);
    }

    return distributedValues;
}) | view::join;
```

Even if this did work with `view::join`, I also think that the mixed metaphor of ranges and loops is also inelegant.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation here; why not alter `is` to hold the transformed data and return it directly? Why do you want a view here at all?

Comment: I simplified the example to make the issue more clear. I actually have a larger pipeline of views. Part of this pipeline creates an object that has a function that returns a collection. I want to get a view of this collection and then join the views to build a larger view. I'm working with a large data set so I don't want it all to be stored in memory simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views do not own the data they present. If you need to ensure the persistence of the data, then the data itself needs to be preserved.

```
auto createRange() {
    //We're using a pointer to ensure that the contents don't get moved around, which might invalidate the view
    std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_set<int>> is_ptr = std::make_unique<std::unordered_set<int>>({1,2,3,4,5,6});
    auto & is = *is_ptr;
    auto view = is | view::transform([](auto&& i) {return i;});
    return std::make_pair(view, std::move(is_ptr));
}

int main() {
    auto[rng, data_ptr] = createRange();
    ranges::for_each(rng, [](auto&& i) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
    });
}
```

An alternate method is to make sure the function is provided the data set from which the view will be created:

```
auto createRange(std::unordered_set<int> & is) {
    return is | view::transform([](auto&& i) {return i;});
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<int> is = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    auto rng = createRange(is);
    ranges::for_each(rng, [](auto&& i) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Either solution should broadly represent what your solution for your project will need to do.

Comment: The first is the approach that I ended up using, but I was hoping there would be a better way to do it within range-v3. For some more context, I have a Rng<Foo>, where Foo has a function that returns a collection. I want to transform that Rng<Foo> into a Rng<Rng<Bar>>, where Bar is based on the collection returned by Foo. I can update my question with more details if that helps.

Comment: @Taylor You'll probably want to update your question.